# How to pull user/author profile data in a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, user-meta, profiles, author-template

My site has a user profile page. For some reason I would like to pull user profile data in my plugin.

I know I can pull logged in user profile data using `get_currentuserinfo();`.

For example I would like to get displayed profile user id.

Can anyone tell me how to pull it.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to get user data for the displayed profile, you can do it like so:

`$thisauthor = get_userdata(intval($author));`

That'll return an object filled with everything you need. For instance, if you need the user ID, you can call it like so:

`$thisauthor->ID`

I use this extensively on the profiles on my site: http://androidandme.com/user/clark

**UPDATE**

In a plugin, it looks like you need to call the global variable first, like so:

`global $author; $thisauthor = get_userdata(intval($author));`

Comment: But the problem is I need the profile id value within a plugin. I've tried your code already. Its not working within a plugin.

Comment: Finally I end up using sessions to store the current profile ID. By the way can you help me with [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71446/how-to-trigger-a-function-when-a-button-clicked) ?

Comment: Does adding a `global $author` help anything?

Comment: You are diamond mate. It works when I add global variable!!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:

get_user_by() at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by

Answer (score 1):

You can access your wp_users table  using `WP_User_Query`.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query

For example:

```
$author_query = new WP_User_Query();

// Get the results
$authors = $author_query->get_results();
```

A more comprehensive example can be seen here: http://wpsmith.net/2012/wp/an-introduction-to-wp_user_query-class/